# Как правильно вызвать асинхронный запрос в react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Есть такой код, который выводит список постов:

```
import React from "react";


type respX = {
    "id": any,
    "userId": any,
    "title": any,
    "body": any,
}

interface PropsI {
}

interface StateI {
    data: respX[];
}

export class ComponentPostList extends React.Component<PropsI, StateI> {

    state: StateI = {data: []}

    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/`);
        const json = await response.json();
        this.setState({data: json});
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="About">
                {this.state.data.map(el => (
                    <li key={el.id}>
                        {el.title}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Как мне при клике на 1 title вывести его body? Или как хотя бы вывести в консоль id элемента, по которому мы кликнули? Вообще желательно при клике на каждом посте (клик на li) делать запрос на отдельные пост
например https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 - где 1 - номер поста.

Answer (score 2):

Вот возможный подход:

1. решите, где в `state` хранить, отображать ли body каждого элемента. Скажем, раз у вас `state.data` – массив объектов типа `respX`, можно ввести в каждом элементе опциональный флаг `isBodyShown?: boolean` (надо будет расширить тип) или хранить флаги отдельно – не в `state.data`, а в отдельном массиве
2. расширьте шаблон чем-то в духе

   ```
               <li key={el.id}>
                   {el.title} {el.isBodyShown ? el.body : ''}
               </li>
   ```

   (тут я добавил plain text, с вёрсткой, думаю, разберётесь)
3. добавьте метод для тогглинга `isBodyShown` по `id` элемента, навесьте на обёртку для `{el.title}`

Вроде всё довольно прямолинейно, но если что-то непонятно, уточните, что.

Comment: @xydope в смысле будет лишний ререндеринг?

Comment: удалил свои коменты, т.к. ерунду написал, не будет лишнего рендеринга. Мы же для этого в реакте ключи элементам массива назначаем. Реакт, при изменении стейта, сравнивает компоненты и рендерит только те, которые изменяются.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Делаем компонент, который возвращает элемент списка. Есть стейт отображения body (по дефолту false), принимает пропсы title, body
class ListItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            bodyDisplayed: false  // стейт отображения
        }
    }
    // функция клика, которая изменяет стейт компонента.
    handleClick() {
        this.setState({ bodyDisplayed: !this.state.bodyDisplayed });
    }

    render() {
       //возвращаем элемент списка, если bodyDisplayed: false, то второй элемент не отрисовывается.
        return (
            <li>
                <span onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>{this.props.title}</span>
                {this.state.bodyDisplayed && <div>{this.props.body}</div>}
            </li>
        )
    }
}

// это ваш мейн, который отрисовывает список и получает данные с сервера.
function App() {
    return (
        <ul>
            {myData.map((dataItem) => <ListItem title={dataItem.title} body={dataItem.body} key={dataItem.key} />)}
        </ul>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: так у меня показываюстя все body. Мне нужно при клике на кажждом посте (клик на li) делать запрос на отдельные пост
например https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 - где 1 - номер поста.

Answer (score 1):

```
async loadPost(id: any) {
        const myResponse = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`);
        const myJson = await myResponse.json();
        this.setState({changedBody: myJson.body, changedTitle: myJson.title});
    }

 <div className="content">
                    <div className="title">{this.state.changedTitle}</div>
                    <div className="article">{this.state.changedBody}</div>
                </div>
                {this.state.data.map(el => (
                    <li onClick={e => this.loadPost(el.id)} key={el.id}>
                        {el.title}
                    </li>
            ))}
```

Comment: если проблема решена, стоит принять какой-нибудь ответ – свой или наиболее полезный чужой